# What happend with the copy css path method in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I remember when I could right click and copy css path in google chrome. Is it disabled or what did change?

Comment: Have you done any research on this ?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about this topic. Can you help me? This would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not in a corporate environment with Group Policies in place to remove this functionality you can go to the elements tab in the developer tools and get the CSS path from there.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

1. Open the website you are debugging.
2. Either inspect the required object by rightclicking on it or pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and choosing the object in the DOM list.
3. In the section with the CSS declarations you can rightclick on the stylesheet name next to the declaration and select *Copy Link Address*

Comment: I guess the question was not about the path to a CSS file, but about the CSS path to a DOM element.